# Can I send request in PUT and DELETE in Delphi 7?

Tags: delphi, rest

I need to send PUT and DELETE along with POST, GET to a REST API how can I do it?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Delphi 7 comes with [Indy](http://www.indyproject.org/Sockets/index.EN.aspx). See the [TIdHTTP component](http://www.indyproject.org/docsite/html/frames.html?frmname=topic&frmfile=!!MEMBEROVERVIEW_TIdHTTP.html) and specificly the Get and Put methods.

Answer (score 4):

Or look at the open source [Synapse](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doku.php/download) library.  There are some simple function calls in the [HTTPSend](http://synapse.ararat.cz/doc/help/httpsend.html) unit which make implementing this completely painless.  Just use the sample functions/procedures as your model for the PUT/DELETE.  The existing routines already supply the POST and GET.  The difference is in the method passed.

Personally I have found this library to be perfectly matched for working with REST.  Its simple, well written and easy to extend.

For example, here is a simple put that sends and receives a stream:

```
function HttpPutBinary(const URL: string; const Data: TStream): Boolean;
var
  HTTP: THTTPSend;
begin
  HTTP := THTTPSend.Create;
  try
    HTTP.Document.CopyFrom(Data, 0);
    HTTP.MimeType := 'Application/octet-stream';
    Result := HTTP.HTTPMethod('PUT', URL);  // changed method from 'POST'
    Data.Size := 0;
    if Result then
    begin
      Data.Seek(0, soFromBeginning);
      Data.CopyFrom(HTTP.Document, 0);
    end;
  finally
    HTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [ICS](http://www.overbyte.be/frame_index.html) components, they are suitable for the job.